# variable of type "System.collections.Arraylist" cannot be converted to System.collections.Generic List in VB NET

Tags: vb.net

I am getting below error in VB.NET in the below code

Variable of type "System.collections.ArrayList" cannot be converted to System.Collection.Generic.List(Of Usertmo). Not sure why i am getting this issue. How to solve this.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Public Class UserArray

    Protected usr As List(Of Usertmo)


    Public Function getUsr() As List(Of Usertmo)
        If (Me.usr Is Nothing) Then
            Me.usr = New ArrayList
        End If

        Return Me.usr
    End Function
End Class
```

Thanks advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the old and superflous `ArrayList` is not a generic `List(Of T)`. So use:

```
Public Function getUsr() As List(Of Usertmo)
    If (Me.usr Is Nothing) Then
        Me.usr = New List(Of Usertmo)()
    End If

    Return Me.usr
End Function
```

You could also use a readonly property:

```
Protected Readonly Property Usr As List(Of Usertmo) = New List(Of Usertmo)()
```